# GCM testing, how to provoke a GCM server response with a canonical_id?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have successfully implemented a client/server Android GCM application. My app server holds a database of device/registration_id pairs. Messages are sent to the devices via web accessible PHP pages. I am trying to write the error handling on the server side, specifically the case where the response contains a canonical_id. The developer docs are quite clear about what needs to be done and why such a response might be produced:

> Canonical IDs
>
> On the server side, as long as the application is behaving well,
>   everything should work normally. However, if a bug in the application
>   triggers multiple registrations for the same device, it can be hard to
>   reconcile state and you might end up with duplicate messages.
>
> GCM provides a facility called "canonical registration IDs" to easily
>   recover from these situations. A canonical registration ID is defined
>   to be the ID of the last registration requested by your application.
>   This is the ID that the server should use when sending messages to the
>   device.
>
> If later on you try to send a message using a different registration
>   ID, GCM will process the request as usual, but it will include the
>   canonical registration ID in the registration_id field of the
>   response. Make sure to replace the registration ID stored in your
>   server with this canonical ID, as eventually the ID you're using will
>   stop working.

So within my Android client app I have a development only button which will register the device with GCMRegistrar.register() a second time without bothering to unregister it first. I had assumed that this would get me a registration_id different from the first time I registered it, and that sending a message to the device from the web (maybe using the old id) would give me a response with a canonical_id.

**However the second registration returns exactly the same reg_id as the first time.**

Thus sending a message via the PHP on my server won't show a canonical_id in the response. I really need to test the situation where a canonical_id is returned, indicating that I need to update my database as my PHP skills are not the finest!

So any ideas as to how I could provoke such a response would be gratefully received

Update: I just tried uninstalling the app from the phone, then reinstalling it. I still get the same reg_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered that question - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808959/canonical-id-and-message-id-format/12978274#12978274).
You can try following the steps I used to get a canonical registration Id. It did involve uninstalling the App, but perhaps you didn't do all the steps I describe there.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. You must have had to try a lot of different, seemingly nonsensical, sequences to finally get a result. Well done.

Comment: Actually I didn't even try to get the canonical reg id. I just tried to get all the possible errors, which is why I uninstalled the app (to get the NotRegistered error). After re-installing the app I was curious to know what would happen if I used the old reg id again. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that canonical id that needs updating will only come from the server. This will only occur if GCM servers detect that they have two ids for a single device.

This might only happen if there is a race condition of some sort, or other bug that is difficult to reproduce. I understand your yearning to test this scenario, but I've been using GCM since it came out of beta and have never seen a canonical id replacement come through.

Comment: My understanding too. However they should provide a test scenario, so that if you put a special extra on the request say, then you will get a canonical_id. How else can they expect developers to write decent, tested apps?

Comment: Or at least give some more concrete idea as to how the duplication could occur. I agree.